# what is the use of TestIntialize attribute, when i can do everything in ClassIntialize in MS testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, in-class-initialization

```
 [ClassInitialize]
    public static void ReportClassSetup(TestContext context)
    {
        BaseAdapter.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PremierConfig"].ConnectionString;
        IServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContextTest();
        var backgroundQueueService = new Camp.Core.Queue.DedicatedThreadTaskQueueService("PremierWebQueueService");
        backgroundQueueService.Start();
        var internalLoggerBackgroundService = new InternalLoggerBackgroundService()
        {
            QueueService = backgroundQueueService
        };
        _service = new InternalService(new DummyAuthorizationManager(), null, null)
        {
            ServiceContext = serviceContext,
            InternalLoggerBackgroundService = internalLoggerBackgroundService
        };
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void ReportTestSetup()
    {

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetUserActivityReport1()
    {
       Assert.IsNotNull(_service.GetUserActivityReport(1));
    }
```

In the above code all the intialization and setup i can do it in classintialize then what is the exact use of TestInitalize?

Comment: only definitions are mentioned there, there's no reason? or practical example as to why to go for testinit ?